# how to create an auto-increment column with a prefix in Adminer with MySQL

Tags: mysql, datatypes, auto-increment, adminer

Adminer 4.8.1 
MySQL

I have 3 tables related to tabata data:

- tabata_exercice_serie
- tabata_exercice_chunk
- tabata_module

#### My problem

in **tabata_module** i have a column "exercice_ids" with array of the Ids from the two tables "tabata_exercice_**serie**" & "tabata_exercice_**chunk**" and because both of them have ID (int)I don't know from wich table it is.

[image]

#### how to create an auto-increment column with a prefix in adminer with MySQL??

For the moment i reached to create an AI ID. To fix my problem my current solution is to have a specific id for "tabata_exercice_**serie**" & "tabata_exercice_**chunk**. For exemple:

- "tabata_exercice_**serie**": E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,...etc
- "tabata_exercice_**chunk**: EC1,EC2,EC3,EC4,EC5,...etc

My problem is when i click on default value and i enter de prefix "E" i have these error log (img2).. I thought it could be that the column type and i also tried all the column types but is always the same error.

[image]

Do you how can i add a prefix value in a AI..?? ChatGPT is telling me to use `CONCAT("E",id)` but i foung it useless because is not going to add Automatically the prefix and i will need to comme and use the function every time i have a new input in the table.

if you have another way around to solve these is issue i'm also intereseted. Thanks

Comment: well i'm a junior and thats the boss choise so i don't have a word on that. But i'm reading the llink you sended me.. Its awesome thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store a delimited list in column, you will have a lot of pain. Take a read on  [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

As per your requirement ,

> how to create an auto-increment column with a prefix

You have the following table, note the id declared as varchar.

```
CREATE TABLE tabata_exercice_serie (
  id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0'
  );
```

We will need to create a sequence table for this table. In this table, we have set the id column to auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE tabata_exercice_serie_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tabata_exercice_serie_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON tabata_exercice_serie 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tabata_exercice_serie_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('E',(LAST_INSERT_ID()));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/HyQXioTL)

You need to perform the same steps for the tabata_exercice_chunk table .

[How to Auto Increment With Prefix As Primary Key in MySQL](https://fedingo.com/how-to-auto-increment-with-prefix-as-primary-key-in-mysql/)

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. I have a qustion can i impact the already existing table or i need to create a new one with your comand ?

Comment: @Rollo you have to modify id from int to varchar on both tables. E1 cant be stored in an int datatype